# Are there any existing Perl wrappers for USPS's new Intelligent Mail barcoding?

Tags: perl

The [USPS provides](https://ribbs.usps.gov/onecodesolution/download.cfm) a C library and a Java wrapper for generating their new Intelligent Mail barcodes. Has anyone found a Perl wrapper? I've used SWIG once before but wanted to see if it's already been done before I went to the trouble. My searching so far has only led to those spam sites that pretend to have whatever your search terms are.

Comment: If you do wind up creating your own wrapper, please consider uploading it to CPAN so the next person with this problem can take advantage of it.

Comment: If there were one on CPAN, [Googling with site:search.cpan.org](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&btn=Google+Search&q=Intelligent%20Mail%20barcode%20site%3Asearch.cpan.org) should find it, and it doesn't.

Comment: Unless something turns up over the weekend it looks like I'll be doing it myself.  I'll look into the CPAN release process.

Comment: You need a free [PAUSE account](http://www.cpan.org/modules/04pause.html) (which you should register for now because it may take a few weeks to process).  I recommend [Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org/) as a good way to simplify the process of creating and uploading a module distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was recently asked at PerlMonks http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=859562. They couldn't find it so unless someone's just done it, it's pretty safe to say -- No.

Comment: That thread does have a link to a [pure-Perl implementation](http://www.w0ep.us/IMBar.pl), although it's not structured as a reusable module.  It might be a starting point, though.

Answer (score 1):

This might be something that you just hook up to Perl with [Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-Java) or [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-C) using the code the USPS provides.

Comment: Oh please, no Inline::C. It's pain down the road and makes distribution via CPAN almost impossible.